# is /user/:id a valid PUT or is /:id only for GET?

Tags: javascript, html, rest

Is `/user/:id` a valid PUT or is `/:id` only for GET?

Should I use headers instead? I am trying to differentiate a create user call and an edit user call. I have done this before but I have a feeling that I haven't been following REST faithfully.

Comment: Going by the ReST way, `POST /users` is a create call, and `PATCH/PUT /users/:id` is an update call.

Comment: Shortly, it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

It does, in some cases, care about whether or not two identifiers are the same.

For example, part of the uniform interface of HTTP is a semantic rule about [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4): caches are required to invalidate the effective request URI "when a non-error status code is received in response to an unsafe request method."

So using the same effective request URI for your PUT as you do for your GET gives you cache invalidation "for free".